# Composer not working correctly for first time user

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying Composer for the first time and am following a tutorial at https://devanswers.co/install-composer-php-windows-10/.

After the install, I've tried the steps in the tutorial but am getting errors:
*( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Timer' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\devforms.gsnetx.org\composerTest\test.php on line 12
( ! ) Error: Class 'Timer' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\devforms.gsnetx.org\composerTest\test.php on line 12*

Line 12 on the test is starting the Timer class:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
Timer::start();
// your code
$time = Timer::stop();
var_dump($time);
print Timer::secondsToTimeString($time);
```

The contents of autoload.php are:

// autoload.php @generated by Composer
require_once **DIR** . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

```
return ComposerAutoloaderInitb589c5929143c1624bdcdde8c7e6fd8b::getLoader();v
```

The directory structure is:

```
composerTest
composerTest\vendor
composerTest\vendor\composer
composerTest\vendor\phpunit
composerTest\vendor\phpunit\php-timer
composerTest\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\src
composerTest\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\tests
```

And the contents of autoload_real.php are:

```
<?php
// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer
class ComposerAutoloaderInitb589c5929143c1624bdcdde8c7e6fd8b
{
    private static $loader;
    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
     */
    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }
        require __DIR__ . '/platform_check.php';
        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitb589c5929143c1624bdcdde8c7e6fd8b', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(\dirname(\dirname(__FILE__)));
```

spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitb589c5929143c1624bdcdde8c7e6fd8b', 'loadClassLoader'));

```
        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';
           call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitb589c5929143c1624bdcdde8c7e6fd8b::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }
        $loader->register(true);
        return $loader;
    }
}
```

From what I can see, all of the paths look correct but, since this is my first time with Composer, I'm clearly not sure what's wrong and would appreciate a point in the right direction.

I'm sure this is not enough information, so please let me know what else is needed to help

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Class 'Timer' not found` - what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where did you define that class?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with `Composer`, it's the way you refer to this class.

You're missing an `use` statement or you need to use the FQCN - Fully-Qualified Class Name completely when using the class.

With your example, you try to load `Timer` class which doesn't exist, the correct FQCN - Fully-Qualified Class Name is `SebastianBergmann\Timer\Timer;`.

So either you mention the class with his correct FQCN (so  `SebastianBergmann\Timer\Timer->start()`) every time or you make use of the `use` statement to just call the simple class name without his namespace this way :

```
use SebastianBergmann\Timer\Timer;
// Timer refers now directly (it's an alias) to SebastianBergmann\Timer\Timer so you can use directly :
Timer::start();
```

Please see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php for this latter and better solution and please see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php for explanation on how namespace works.